# ensure_future not available in module asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run this example from the [python asyncio tasks & coroutines documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#example-future-with-run-forever)

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def slow_operation(future):
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    future.set_result('Future is done!')

def got_result(future):
    print(future.result())
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.Future()
asyncio.ensure_future(slow_operation(future))
future.add_done_callback(got_result)
try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensure_future'
```

This is the line that seems to be causing me grief:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(slow_operation(future))
```

My python interpreter is 3.4.3 on OSX Yosemite, as is the version of documentation I linked to above, from which I copied the example, so I **shouldn't** be getting this errror. Here's a terminal-grab of my python interpreter:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Feb 25 2015, 21:28:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Other examples from the page not referencing `asyncio.ensure_future` seem to work.

I tried opening a fresh interpreter session and importing `ensure_future` from `asyncio`

```
from asyncio import ensure_future
```

I get an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_future'
```

I have access to another machine running Ubuntu 14.04 with python 3.4.0 installed. I tried the same import there, and unfortunately faced the same import error.

Has the api for asyncio been changed and its just not reflected in the documentation examples, or maybe there's a typo and ensure_function should really be something else in the documentation?

Does the example work (or break) for other members of the SO community?

Thanks.

Comment: "My python interpreter is 3.4.3 on OSX Yosemite, as is the version of documentation I linked to above" - As you now know, this is not correct. The docs are [continuously updated](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2015-June/692446.html), so unfortunately sometimes this means new methods are introduced in the docs before they are actually released.

Comment: Thanks! that's what was pointed out in the accepted answer. Usually, python standard library api doesn't change with minor version upgrades, but asyncio is in the standard library on a provisional basis. I should have realized that sooner.

Comment: @haleemur Ali can you help for this ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38531354/6626256

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future

> `asyncio.ensure_future(coro_or_future, *, loop=None)`
>
> Schedule the execution of a coroutine object: wrap it in a future. Return a Task object.
>
> If the argument is a `Future`, it is returned directly.
>
> **New in version 3.4.4.**

That's about it for "[Who is to blame?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_to_Blame%3F)". And regarding "[What is to be done?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_to_Be_Done%3F_%28novel%29)":

> `asyncio.async(coro_or_future, *, loop=None)`
>
> A deprecated alias to `ensure_future().`
>
> Deprecated since version 3.4.4.

Comment: Hello. How would you write a single codebase that supports both Python 3.4.3 and 3.4.4?

Comment: @AmirEldor I leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: I was thinking about doing a terrible thing with if sys.version_info. Then I thought about a try: except: clause. Then I thought this place is not for discussion about it.

Comment: @AmirEldor Sigh. Either use `.async` since it's still there or (cleaner) `if hasattr` (`getattr(,,default)` is flawed since it'll always evaluate the default), then save the reference locally.